# Oracle table column contain $

Tags: oracle

I'm currently migrating AIX to Linux. The Oracle script contains a $ in the column name. While fetching through the shell script, I set the escape character to $, but it does not work. The query is like below:

```
Set escape $

Select c.logoff$time from temp c;
```

When run from shell script I'm getting "c.logoff invalid identifier".

How can I fix this?

Comment: What did you think "escape character" means? Whatever your guess, it's probably incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an SQL*Plus (I assume that's your client) problem, so the `set escape` isn't doing anything - that's for escaping things SQL*Plus tries to interpret - [see the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG078).

This is a shell issue/feature. the `$time` part is being treated as a shell variable, and that doesn't exist, so the final table name doesn't have it. You can escape that at shell level, referring to `\$time`; e.g. if you're using a heredoc:

```
sqlplus -s -l usr/pass@db <<EOF

select c.logoff\$time from temp c;

EOF
```